# Writing a custom collection form type for symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

I am trying to create a custom form Type for a collection of objects so that I can render it in a particular way.

As a somewhat understandable example, I have a `User`, each with a variable number of `Car` objects. A `User` can (optionally) also have an `Information` object associated with them. For this example, this includes:

- Their age
- Their height

The user's cars are also ranked by how fast they are and how heavy they are. So the database would be represented like this:

```
class Review
{
  // The user this feedback refers to.
  /**
   * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
   */
  private $user;

  private $age;
  private $height;

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CarRanking", inversedBy="review")
   */
  private $car_rankings;

  //...
}

class CarRanking
{
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Review", mappedBy="car_rankings")
   */
  private $review;

  /**
   * The car this ranking is for.
   * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Car")
   */
  private $car;

  // These are both rankings, from 1 to however many cars the user owns.
  private $speed;
  private $weight;

  //...
}
```

So a full review might be something like this:

'Bob' - age: 35, height: 180,
Car 1 - speed: 1, weight: 3,
Car 2 - speed: 2, weight: 1,
Car 3 - speed: 3, weight: 2

I am trouble presenting this in a form to the user using Symfony's forms. Ideally I would like to produce something like this:

```css
input, label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>How old is this person?</label>
  <input type="number" id="age" />

  <label>How tall are they?</label>
  <input type="number" id="height" />

  <label>Please rank their cars by speed</label>

  <select id="car_rankings_speed_0">
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="0">1</option>
    <option value="1">2</option>
    <option value="2">3</option>
  </select>

  <select id="car_rankings_speed_1">
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="0">1</option>
    <option value="1">2</option>
    <option value="2">3</option>
  </select>

  <select id="car_rankings_speed_2">
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="0">1</option>
    <option value="1">2</option>
    <option value="2">3</option>
  </select>

  <label>Please rank their cars by weight</label>

  <select id="car_rankings_weight_0">
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="0">1</option>
    <option value="1">2</option>
    <option value="2">3</option>
  </select>

  <select id="car_rankings_weight_1">
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="0">1</option>
    <option value="1">2</option>
    <option value="2">3</option>
  </select>

  <select id="car_rankings_weight_2">
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="0">1</option>
    <option value="1">2</option>
    <option value="2">3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

I have tried creating different types to accomplish this, including a `collection` of `RankingType`s, which is just a fancy `select` that initializes the correct number of items. But each CarRanking groups by car, rather than weight or speed.

I have also tried creating a `CarRankingType`, but need to get at the underlying data somehow, and when I have it, I'm not sure what I'd do with it.

Is there a particular way to accomplish this, or some other way of going about it? I am not having fun with Symfony's forms.

Comment: Yep.  S2 forms can be a pain once you get outside their little box.  This http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html shows you how to access the instance data and build your form dynamically.  Good luck.  I myself have started to migrate away from S2 forms.

Comment: @Cerad What are you using instead? Assuming you're still using Symfony.

Comment: Still a big fan of Symfony.  Just not using twig and pretty much building my forms manually.

Comment: @Cerad seriously, how can you not love twig?!